# Issues with kSqlDB client for Java in Quarkus app - BatchedQueryResult hangs on completableFuture get()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, quarkus, ksqldb

This is my Java code

```
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.BatchedQueryResult;
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.Client;
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.ClientOptions;
import io.confluent.ksql.api.client.Row;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class KSqlDBTest {
    public static String KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST = "localhost";
    public static int KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT = 8088;

    @Test
    public void kSqlDbTest() {
        ClientOptions options = ClientOptions.create()
                .setHost(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST)
                .setPort(KSQLDB_SERVER_HOST_PORT)
                .setUseTls(false)
                .setUseAlpn(false)
                .setExecuteQueryMaxResultRows(1000000000);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        Client client = Client.create(options);
        try {
            String pullQuery = "SELECT * FROM QUERYABLE_CLIENTS_VEHICLES;";
            BatchedQueryResult batchedQueryResult = client.executeQuery(pullQuery, (Map)properties);
            List<Row> resultRows = batchedQueryResult.get();

            System.out.println("Received results. Num rows: " + resultRows.size());
            for (Row row : resultRows) {
                System.out.println("Row: " + row.values());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the execution of the following line of code gets stuck:

```
List<Row> resultRows = batchedQueryResult.get();
```

Right after executing it, I actually see this log on the kSqlDB server:

```
INFO 172.21.0.1 - - [Wed, 20 Sep 2023 14:00:19 GMT] "POST /query-stream HTTP/2.0" 200 1030 "-" "ksqlDB Java Client v7.4.0" 142 (io.confluent.ksql.api.server.LoggingHandler)
```

But the execution hangs on Java side.

Some considerations:

- My kSqlDb server is up and running in a docker container on my local machine. Here's the result to a call to GET /info endpoint:

  {
  "KsqlServerInfo": {
  "version": "7.4.0",
  "kafkaClusterId": "nq0iysPOTMeoaTizkPidNw",
  "ksqlServiceId": "default_",
  "serverStatus": "RUNNING"
  }
  }
- The QUERYABLE_CLIENTS_VEHICLES materialized table is correctly
  created, and the query "SELECT * FROM QUERYABLE_CLIENTS_VEHICLES;"
  when executed directly from confluent console works with no
  problems
- I also tried to directly call thekSqlDB REST endpoint POST
  /query-stream passing the same query, and    it works with no
  problems
- There is no exception catched by the code.

What could be the issue?

Comment: is there a way to lower the timeout of the "get()" ? it will be easier if you put a reproducer.

Comment: The reproducer is basically the jUnit test code that I posted, you just need to put it into a quarkus project and add the needed dependencies. The timeout in the get() is not the issue here, I don't expect that query to take a lot of time, in fact it takes around a few milliseconds when run via REST API on ksql, so the fact that the get() call hangs is not due to actual execution time.